# View appearing twice when performing segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, segue

I have an issue with my app. i'm using Navigation Controller and TableView.
So in my first View I have a TableView named `propTableView`, it's a list of property. When I click on a cell it brings me to an other ViewController with an other TableView named `propDetailTableView`. I perform a Segue from `PropViewController` to `PropDetailViewController` :

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *sectionTitle = [aromaPropSectionTitles objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    NSArray *sectionProp = [propData objectForKey:sectionTitle];
    propName = [sectionProp objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"PropDetail" sender:self];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"PropDetail"]) {
        PropViewController *propView = segue.destinationViewController;
        propView.title = propName;
        SQLmanager *sqlManager = [[SQLmanager alloc] initDatabase:@"prop_max.sqlite3"];
        NSString *propRequest = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT id_prop FROM prop_max WHERE prop_name_fr LIKE '%@'", propName];
        NSLog(@"propRequest = %@", propRequest);
        NSString *propId = [sqlManager getString:propRequest];
        NSLog(@"propId = %@", propId);
    }
}
```

For now I just change the Title of the Navigation Bar. But the behaviour is not normal. Instead of displaying the `PropDetailViewController` with the new title it displays the new PropDetailViewController with the precedent title (if it's the first time I click on a cell it displays no title), and then it displays the `PropDetailViewController` with the title. 
It wouldn't be a problem, but when I click on  `Back` in the upper left it bring me back to the `PropDetailViewController` with the old title, and I have to click a second time on `Back` to return to the `PropViewController`.

I click on a cell (I clicked on Anti-Douleur before, but now I choose Actif-Cosémtique): 
[image: Actif Cosmétique]

It displays this : 
[image: Old Title]

Then a second after : 
[image: Good Title]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah sorry I know what the problem is.

It's this simple:

prepareForSegue runs WAY BEFORE THE UIView IS SET UP.

It only concerns the view controller, not the view.

What you have to do is...

SET SOME INFORMATION during the segue....

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
  {
  if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"idUber"])
    {
    Uber *uber = [segue destinationViewController];
    uber.classnameToUse = .. whatever ...;
    }
  }
```

and then in that other class... MUCH LATER, WHEN viewDidLoad RUNS, then use that information.

note - **viewDidAppear** may be more appropriate, depending on your situation

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
  {
  [self loadThisMainSection:self.classnameToUse];

  // note that back during the segue you have CORRECTLY SET .classnameToUse
  // that was a long time ago.  but we only use it now.
  }
```

it's that simple!

You have to do this in every segue situation.

You end up with variable names like "whenYouCanUseThisValue"....

In your case you need a property called:

```
@property (strong) NSString *useThisTitleLaterWhenYouAreLoading;
```

BTW don't forget that if it is a non-class property, it's "assign"

```
@property (assign) CGPoint afterLoadingHereIsThePosition;
@property (assign) CGFloat onceYouLoadUseThisAlpha;
```

Comment: there's no reason it shouldn't work (1) you need to add a new property in your class PropDetailViewController which would be an (strong) string.  call it "shouldBeTitle" for example.  set that in the prepareForSegue.  then in viewDidAppear, log it and see if it's right.  if so set the title!  note try viewdidappear, as well as viewdidload.  depends on what you are doing

Comment: Yeah I did that but there is still 1 view appearing just before the right view is set.

Comment: are you saying when you click ONE cell, in fact it makes TWO new PropDetailViewController ?

Comment: YEAH ! THat's what I mean. I thought the screenshot were self-explanatory

Comment: No it was unclear.   OK you just have some problem when you call the code. You have another invisible table, or whatever.  add some logs to see how often it gets called

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62979/discussion-between-nicolas-charvoz-kurzawa-and-joe-blow).

Comment: I opened a chat. The segue if performed twice ! See details in chat